# Replace succeeding number with zero using if statement

Tags: php, if-statement

I have these result set using loop condition and would output the following:

```
 |    50,000  |
 |    50,000  |
 |    50,000  |
 |   100,000  |
 |   100,000  |
 |   300,000  |
 |   300,000  |
```

What i would like to happen is change the succeeding number to zero (0),showing only unique values like:

```
 |    50,000  |
 |         0  |
 |         0  |
 |   100,000  |
 |         0  |
 |   300,000  |
 |         0  |
```

How can i achieve this one using if else statement?

Here is the code that generates the result:

```
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($borrower_details['borrower_ledger']->result_array() as $ledger) { ?>
             <tr>
                 <td>
                   <?php 
                       $query2 = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " .tbl_loan_master." WHERE id = ".$ledger['loanmaster_id']." AND deleted = 0");
                       $loan_bal = $query2->row()->loan;

                       echo $loan_bal;
                    ?>
                 </td>
              </tr>
          <?php } ?>
      </tbody>
```

Comment: can you post the code that generates this result?

Comment: i just updated the post @AnatPort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear from the context, so there might be a need for placing zeroes instead of repeating non-unique values, but maybe `array_unique` can help you?

**Elaborated the answer:**

1. If you just want to gather all unique values from the list of values - just use `array_unique`: a) before echoing gather all the loan values; 2) Build your table with `foreach (array_unique($loan_values) as $loan_value) ...`
2. If you want to preserve the repeating values, but replace them with zeroes, than use an additional array to store unique values and `echo` accordingly: a) add `$uniqueValues = [];` before the `foreach`; b) Add the following logic before echoing `$loan_bal`:

   if (in_array($loan_bal, $uniqueValues)) {
       $loan_bal = 0; }
   else {
       $uniqueValues[] = $loan_bal; }
   echo $loan_bal;

*Sorry for poor code formatting, the markdown failed on me.*

Comment: @zen Expanded the answer, see above.

Comment: thank you soo much @BVengerov it works great! I really do appreciate you're help. You're the man!!!